# Android backstack fragments and data saving

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, stack, nav

I've been struggling with this problem for like a week, it's basically a Backstack problem I didn't found an optimal solution yet. I am working on a project which's flow is like this:

`Activity (Fragment_A -> Fragment_B -> Fragment_C -> Fragment_A)`

I am setting on `Fragment_A` one `DatePicker` and a `TimePicker` and I have 2 `TextViews` that redirect the user to `Fragment_B`. From `Fragment_B` I send some data to `Fragment_C` that converts the data and sends it back to `Fragment_A`.

The problem is that as far as I've understood is that when going back to `Fragment_A` it goes with a new instance, not the old, so my data there is lost. I resolved for now with `sharedPreferences` but it seems too complicated for a solution. I've tried with custom `beginTransaction()` and `Navigation component` but it didn't turn out well.

I was close, and when going from `Fragment_C` to `Fragment_A` there was the new instance on top of the old and at `onBackPressed` it popped the new instance, and showed me the old but how can I resolve so I won't need to press the back button? I tried to send a Boolean so if it's a new instance pop it, but it popped the old one I guess, because when I pressed back, it just quit the Activity instead of popping the new one.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Activity-scoped `ViewModel` will make sharing data between child `Fragments` easier. Your `Fragments` observe the data in the `ViewModel`, so you don't even have to worry about passing data around. And with Navigation Component, you can use `popUpTo` and `popUpToInclusive` to pop `Fragments` B and C off the back stack, leaving just `Fragment` A.

If you're not familiar with these concepts, this free course covers them all wonderfully:

https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps-with-kotlin--ud9012

Comment: That course got me into Android development, and I had the ```Navigation component``` part with ```popUpTo``` and ```popUpToInclusive``` with the ```sharedPreferences``` as the solution I've found. The thing that was missing was the Activity-scoped ```ViewModel``` for as I had separate ones for every ```Fragment```. I implemented it as you said, and now I can keep the 2 Picker data in ```Fragment_A```, I'll try for the rest and I'll come back to vote if it will work as an overall solution. Thanks a lot!